Open Editing in Android Studio Option
I was working on my project and unfortunately click on hide option and now i need this option in my project  anyone know how to show this option again in android studio. I try to appear that by multiple ways but not be successful.
Option is Targeted There

Trivial suggestion: have you tried closing the file and reopening it? Or closing the whole Android studio?

what AS are you using? big chance that this was just removed in newer version
